# In a system of two ordinary differential equations that's equivalent to a simple harmonic oscillator, how can a function's derivative be - and +?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a very basic question which hopefully somebody will have the patience to help me answer. I'm learning about ordinary differential equations, and I'm trying to think about the "Romeo and Juliet" system that Steve Strogatz proposed:

$$\begin{align}\frac{dr}{dt} & -= -a j(t) \\ \frac{dj}{dt}& = b r(t)\end{align}$$

where $a,b>0$. I found a general solution for $r$ and $j$:

$$\begin{align}j & = c_1 \sin{(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)} +c_2 \cos{(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)} \\ r & = d_1 \sin{(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)}+d_2 \cos{(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)}\end{align}$$

And, according to mathematica, plugging those solutions (?) back into the system of differential equations reduces the number of arbitrary constants to two, so that:

$$\begin{align}j & = \frac{c_2 \cdot \sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \sin(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)+c_1\cos(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t) \\ r & =\frac{-c_1 \cdot \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \sin(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)+c_2\cos{(\sqrt{ab}\cdot t)}\end{align}$$

I put these equations into a function plotting software (Desmos) to see what they look like together and to play with the parameters $,,c_1,$ and $c_2$, and that's where my confusion came. I chose some values of those parameters and got this result:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=14tJME90fCbz9CTAaz7vGIZZu5unZeFgH

In that picture, $()$ is black and $()$ is red. I'm having trouble understanding why these waves can be in phase; for example, at a point $=_0$ a little before the simultaneous peak of both functions (where they're both rising,) $()$ is clearly positive and $$ is chosen to be positive, so $−\cdot ()$ is negative, but a tangent line to the black curve is positive, so $/$ is positive. I'm sure my confusion must lie in a mistake in my calculation somewhere (probably the part that mathematica did and that I didn't understand) and I'd really appreciate if somebody would take the time to point it out to me.

Also, I recognize that by plugging one of the first equations into the other one achieves the equation for either of the functions describing a harmonic oscillator, $d^2 r/dt^2=-ab r(t)$, and I'm comfortable with that; my confusion is really just with the phase.

On the mathoverflow forum, [Nate Eldredge was kind enough](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422081/481928) to try and replicate the image above; he made a [Desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iocr9r6tti) that plots $j,r$.  When I started to fiddle with it, a choice of parameters which produced a graph that was similarly confusing to me in his calculator was $(a,b,c_1,c_2)=(10,0.5,1,1)$.  In case anybody would prefer to jump directly to the graph with those parameters, [here it is](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wwlijl86my).  Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: In your Desmos links, it's the *red* curve that's given by your formula for $r(t)$, not the blue curve as you seem to think.

Comment: Thanks for the comment—how can you tell?  I'm confused about the difference in phase between the curves, so it doesn't naively seem like which curve corresponds to which function should be related to the confusion, but it might be essential in some way that I'm not recognizing.

Comment: On the left of the screen, in the area where you adjust the parameters, there's a **blue** curve symbol next to the formula for $j(t)$, and a **red** curve symbol next to the formula for $r(t)$.

Comment: And also without that information, you could identify which curve is which by (for example) setting $c_1=0$ and $c_2 = 1$.

Comment: The desmos calculator used to generate the linked image was distinct from the linked calculators in the final paragraph of the question

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't look carefully at that first image. That picture is clearly completely wrong, but it's impossible to say what the mistake is if you don't give a link to how it was generated in Desmos. Maybe you accidentally switched $c_1$ and $c_2$ in one of the equations?

Comment: The problem was indeed my mistake in copying the solutions into Desmos; it was a little frustrating to find that that was the source of the confusion, but I'm glad to have had a reason to become very comfortable with the system and its solutions.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The ode system

$$
\cases{
\dot r = -a j\\
\dot j = b r
}
$$

can be represented as

$$
\dot p = M p
$$

with $p = (r, j)'$ and $M=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -a \\
 b & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ but $M = T\Lambda T^{-1}$ with $T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{i \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} & \frac{i \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -i \sqrt{ab} & 0 \\
 0 & i \sqrt{ab} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

then we have

$$
T\dot p = \Lambda T p
$$

now calling $P = T p$ we follow with

$$
\dot P = \Lambda P
$$

This is a diagonal ode system equivalent to

$$
\cases{
\dot P_1 = -i\sqrt{ab}P_1\\
\dot P_2 = i\sqrt{ab}P_2\\
}
$$

and with solution

$$
\cases{
P_1 = e^{-i\sqrt{ab}t}p_{01}\\
P_2 = e^{i\sqrt{ab}t}p_{02}\\
}
$$

two oscillators with the same frequency but with phase and amplitude that can differ by virtue of $p_{0i}$.

Comment: I think I followed this diagonalization, but my confusion remains: if, for instance, $p_{01}=p_{02}$, and one were to plot $T^{-1}P_1$ and $T^{-1}P_2$, wouldn't the same behavior that's confusing me appear on that graph?  Thanks very much for the help

Comment: With the same initial conditions we will have as the solution set $(r=-\frac{c_0}{\sin\phi}\sin(\sqrt{ab}t-\phi),j=\frac{c_0}{\cos\phi}\cos(\sqrt{ab}t-\phi))$ with $\phi = \arctan(\frac ba)$.

Comment: I have that $T^{-1} P = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{-i}{2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}p_{01} \exp{(-i\sqrt{ab}t)}\\p_{02}\exp{(-i\sqrt{ab}t)}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{ip_{01}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\exp{(-i\sqrt{ab}t)}+\frac{p_{02}}{2}\exp{(-i\sqrt{ab}t)} \\ \frac{-i p_{01}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\exp{(-i\sqrt{ab}t)}+\frac{p_{02}}{2}\exp{(-i\sqrt{ab}t)}\end{bmatrix}$, and I'm having trouble identifying the difference between these equations and the simplified pair of equations for $r$ and $j$ w.r.t. phase.

Comment: Looking just at the real components of those equations, it seems as though Romeo and Juliet oscillate totally in phase, which is the maximally confusing case to me.

Comment: Hence the name Romeo and Juliet...

Comment: The behavior which the name refers to, I think based upon some scene in the play in which Romeo pulls away from some kissing, is that when Juliet's attraction to Romeo is positive, Romeo's attraction to Juliet is decreasing, and when Romeo's attraction to Juliet is positive, Juliet's attraction is increasing (and vice versa for each of those conditionals.) As in the original question, this is my confusion (which I recognize by now must be somehow very basic): if the waves $j(t)$ and $r(t)$ are in  phase, then when $j(t)$ is positive, a tangent line to $r(t)$ ($r$'s _rate of change_) is +ve.

Comment: **Note** that I don't mean that this is the case for all positive values of $j$, just for the regions over which $j$ and $r$ are harmoniously ascending between 0 and some peak.